# Use regex to search strings with similar structure

Tags: regex

I am trying to search titles in a bibtex file and only get titles as output.

For instance, when I read a bibtex text line by line it would be strings in a list:

```
['\tPages = {3221--52},\n',
 '\tTitle = {The slave trade and the origins of mistrust in Africa},\n',
 '\tVolume = {101},\n',
 '\tYear = {2011}}\n',
 '\n',
 '@article{perez2013regime,\n',
 "\tAuthor = {P{\\'e}rez-Li{\\~n}{\\'a}n, An{\\'\\i}bal and Mainwaring, Scott},\n",
 '\tDate-Added = {2019-03-06 15:28:11 -0800},\n',
 '\tDate-Modified = {2019-03-06 15:28:11 -0800},\n',
 '\tJournal = {Comparative Politics},\n',
 '\tNumber = {4},\n',
 '\tPages = {379--397},\n',
 '\tPublisher = {City University of New York},\n',
 '\tTitle = {Regime legacies and levels of democracy: evidence from Latin America},\n',
 '\tVolume = {45},\n']
```

From here, I would only want to get the titles:

```
The slave trade and the origins of mistrust in Africa
Regime legacies and levels of democracy: evidence from Latin America
```

How can I do this with `regex`?

Potentially I want something like:

```
for line in lines:
    pattern = re.compile( regex here )
    result = pattern.search(line)
    if (result):
        print(result.group())
```

I followed the answer below but it won't print the results:

```
string = '\tTitle = {Regime legacies and levels of democracy: evidence from Latin America},\n'
pattern = re.compile(r'^\\tTitle = \{(.*)\},\\n$')
result = pattern.match(string)
if (result):
    print(result.group(1))
```

I get no results, meaning there was no match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
^\\tTitle = \{(.*)\},\\n$
```

use match instead of search

Comment: the regex is fine https://regex101.com/r/VRZNHm/1 it could be a problem with your code

Comment: Yes it seems so -- but why won't it work with `re.compile`? I pasted in my question.

Comment: I think it has to do with the single vs double \